# What does this for loop's condition do?

Tags: c, for-loop

This is a program for converting letters to upper case.

Could anyone explain me what the condition of the for loop in the below program does?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[50];
    gets(a);

    for(i=0;a[i];i++)
      a[i]=toupper(a[i]);

    puts(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A null byte has the value zero. An expression is false if it's equal to zero, true otherwise. Combine this and you got it.

Comment: It just gets the `i`th value of the array `a`. If its zero, the loop terminates; if it's nonzero, it continues.

Comment: For the love of!... Don't use `gets()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets()` will return a 0-terminated string, as all C strings should be. So if you entered "four", the actual contents added to `a` will be those four letters followed by a `0` byte.

```
 // as if you'd declared
 char a[] = { 'f', 'o', 'u', 'r', 0 };
```

The loop tests each character to see that it's not `0`. When `a[i]` is `0`, the condition fails, and the loop ends.  It's simply looping over all of the actual characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

`a[i]` evaluates to non-zero (true) for all the characters except the terminating null character. Hence, the loop breaks when `a[i]` is the terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, strings in C have a zero byte at the end to indicate the end of the string. The for checks for this byte and stops executing when it is reached because all non-zero bytes in the string evaluate to true.